Examples of Taleb's explanation of "exponential"?
Am requesting some examples (of actual mathematical functions) that fit what Taleb (@nero) describes here:



As the text states, $e^x$ satisfies this.  As does any constant times $e^x$.

@lulu is this correct? d(e^x)/dx = xe^(x-1)? If yes, then how did we get e^x = xe^(x-1)? (Feel free to elaborate in an "answer" post. If I understand it, I'll mark it the correct answer. Thanks.)

No, $d(e^x)/dx=e^x$; perhaps you’re confusing exponential function of $x$ with polynomial function of $x$, e.g., $d(x^n)/dx=nx^{n-1}$

@J.W.Tanner Yes, you are correct. I am. I'm going to look up how to take derivatives of e. Looks like it's a different family.

No, the text is looking for solutions to $\frac d{dx} f(x)=f(x)$.  For any constant $C$, $Ce^x$ is such a solution.

No.  $\frac {d x^n}{dx} = nx^{n-1}$.  But $x^n$ is a very different thing than $n^x$.  The derivative of $n^x$ is NOT $x n^{x-1}$ at all!.  The derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$ itself.  That's actually the definition (sort of) of $e^x$.  The derivative of $n^x$ is $(\ln n) n^x$.  Note that $\ln n$ is a constant so the derivative of $n^x$ is proportional to $n^x$.  This is what Taleb is getting at.

@fleablood Thank you. You pointed out a major blindspot in what I was thinking (that x^n is not the same as n^x).

I recommend trying (and I mean trying-- it's okay to get stuck) figuring the derivative to see how this works: $\lim \frac {b^{x+h}-b^x}h=\lim\frac {b^xe^h-b^x}h=\lim\frac{b^x(1-b^h)}h= b^x\cdot \lim\frac {1-b^h}h$.  Now $\lim\frac {1-b^h}h$, whatever it is, has nothing to do with $x$ so it is a constant. So the derivative of $b^x = C_bb^x$ where $C_b=\lim \frac{1-b^h}h$ is a constant that depends on $b$. As it turns out, $C_b=\lim\frac {1-b^h}h=\ln b$ but what really matters is that it is a constant.

If you compare the graphs of $n^x$ to $x^n$ you see they are quite distinct.  $n^x$ may start slow (and it tails infinitely to $0$ in one direction) but will suddenly grow, and grow very fast (hence the phrase "exponential growth").  The curve to me always resemble a slug rearing up to a steep wall, but... well, your imagery will almost certainly vary.  But it's a very distinct shape.

One minor note is that, if we use a base $b$ rather than $e$, then $\frac{d}{dx}b^x=(\ln b) b^x$. So in those cases, the derivatives of $b^x$ are proportional to $b^x$ itself. The nice thing about $e^x$ is that its derivatives are all equal to $e^x$.
